# Xcode not displaying object descriptions

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I'm developing a Mac app, and I've updated to OS X El Capitan GM seed (but I'm still on Xcode 6.4). I'm not sure if it's related to the updates but when debugging, Xcode is not displaying description of my local variables anymore, it's just displaying their addresses:

[image]

It's just an example run, it's always the same no matter my object types are or what method I am in. I've cleaned build folder, removed derived data etc. but no avail, still the same.

Why would this happen?